# Excel VBA : Convert date format from YYYY-MM-DD-HH.MM.SS.Milli to DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS

Tags: excel, vba, date, datetime

I have the following datetime to convert into format `DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS`

Cell type : General

```
2011-01-29-10.23.23.123100
```

## My try:

Function:

```
Function ConvertDate(D1 As Date) As Long

 ConvertDate = Substitute(Substitute(Substitute(D1, "/", " ", 3), ".", ":", 1), ".", ":", 1) * 1

End Function
```

Result:

```
#VALUE!
```

Unable to get expected result.

Comment: try with `Function ConvertDate(D1 As string) As Date` and `ConvertDate = CDate(Left(D1, 10) & " " & Replace(Mid(D1, 12, 8), ".", ":"))` and just format the output like you want it...

Comment: @DirkReichel, Perfect! Does good job.

Comment: @DirkReichel, Can i concatenate string "Time" at the end of ConvertDate from function?

Comment: @DirkReichel, I tried by using `ConvertDate = ConvertDate & "Time"` but not getting the expected result.

Comment: If you're using string manipulation for this task you're likely doing it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Use,

```
=--LEFT(REPLACE(SUBSTITUTE(A1, ".", ":"), 11, 1, CHAR(32)), 20)
```

(or the VBA equivalent). Format (or set the [Range.NumberFormat property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196401.aspx)) as `DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS`.

[image: replace_date]
            <sup>Note that A1 is left-aligned (i.e. *text* ) and B1 is right-aligned (i.e. true *number* or *date* )</sup>